# Controller Design Using Webots! (Heading, Velocity, tilt,balance)

Tags: control, software, first-robotics, webots

I am trying to design and implement certain controllers for a robot. **I am currently designing controllers for the robot, where it aims to control the Heading, Velocity, Tilt, Balance of the robot.** Could someone guide me on how to implement this using WEBOTS?

Comment: Sorry, the correction has been made. Till now I have worked on designing the robot with sensor. Now I need to begin with the designing part , aiming at the heading, tilt, and the velocity control of the robot.

Comment: @jsotola I am not referring to the tutorials. I am working on different implementation of a robot. I want to discuss the Heading, Velocity, Tilt, Balance control aspects of the robot, and implement controllers for these aspects. The robot is not the Epuck robot but something I made myself! :)